# After Jesus death and resurrection are there any other incidents in the NT where Jesus/God makes promises of salvation to individuals?

Tags: jesus, new-testament, heaven

Before his death and resurrection Jesus promises salvation to the thief on the cross (Luke 23:43). Are there any similar incidents after his resurrection?

Extra question: why does Jesus promise the thief salvation in the first place?

Comment: Welcome to BH. _And he said unto them, Go ye into all the world, and preach the gospel to every creature.He that believeth and is baptized shall be saved;._ Mark 16:16 KJV. The promise of salvation is to all who believe the gospel.

Comment: Hi Keynes, welcome to BHSE. Please take the [Site Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) when you get a chance, which explains more about the SE format and what kind of questions to ask here. This question seems to be [searching for a text](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/520/what-are-we-looking-for-in-answers/533#533) and is likely to be closed.

Comment: @SteveTaylor thanks Steve. Yes this question is searching for particular bible passages. Is there another exchange where this might be more appropriate?

Comment: Essentially, this type of question is not well suited to the StackExchange format, and is generally avoided on most SE sites due to its tendency to reduce the quality of Questions and Answers, which makes it harder for new users to write good questions/answers, and understand how to improve in how they use the site. In general it's encouraged to just use a search engine or forum. Please see [this Meta post](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4199/wheres-the-boundary-line-with-the-verse-identification-tag/4200#4200) over on the Christianity site for more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Actually keynes Jesus (after His resurrection) said to His disciples at Matthew 28:18-20, "All authority has been given to Me in heaven and on earth, vs19, Go therefore and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father and the Son and the Holy Spirit, vs20, teaching them to observe all that I have commanded you; and lo, I am with you always, even to the end of the age."

Notice He says to make disciples first, and then they are baptized. With regard to the thief he was saved by faith. He admitted that he deserved to be punished for his crimes and ask that Jesus would remember him. Jesus knew the thief's heart and that he admitted his crimes and ask Jesus to remember him when You come in Your kingdom.

Jesus said to him, "Truly I say to you, today you shall be with Me in Paradise. (Luke 23:42-43). The thing to keep in mind is that the thief was saved by grace through faith. Those who lived and died before the incarnation of Jesus were saved by looking forward in faith to His coming.

Those of us today are saved by grace through faith in the Redeemer Jesus Christ who has already come. Lastly, (and I feel this is important to note), the thief was not water baptized and yet was saved for believing in Jesus Christ.

Comment: So in Matthew 28:18-20 Jesus clearly instructs the disciples to baptise everyone. Can this be read as a requirement for salvation? From your last paragraph it sounds like you don’t believe so (“saved by grace through faith”) - why not?

Comment: The short answer is that water baptism is not essential to salvation. Ephesians 2:8-9, "For by grace you have been saved through faith, and that not of yourselves, it is the GIFT of God; not as a result of works, that no one should boast." We get water baptized after were saved to identify with our Lord's death and resurrection. And yes, we are commanded and we are suppose to get baptized. However, there are certain circumstances in life where it is impossible to get water baptized but the person is still reckoned righteous before God through his faith. Example, the thief on the cross.